# How to add a css styled html-list to wordpress, manageable in the dashboard

Tags: php, css, wordpress, html-lists

I would like to add a feature to a WordPress page to display a short list of people, like the one seen here - http://www.blenderbox.com/company/team

I have done this on other sites by styling lists with css. This time however, it's for a client and I can't trust them to copy and paste a `<li>`, editing the name, job title and img name without messing it up.

What is the best way to go about creating this so that it can be easily reduced/added to in the WordPress dashboard? Basically, so that the user simply clicks "add person" then fills in some fields before updating the page.

I'm new to WordPress (though I understand how it works) but I am competent coding so hopefully an informative nudge in the right direction would be sufficient.

Thanks, Ben.

Comment: If this isn't a coding problem, it should probably go on the Wordpress  Stack Exchange instead, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about working with Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Use categories. Create a new category called Person or Team or something to that effect. Then use the Post Title for their Name - any other information can be put in the post and then add the image to the Featured Image.

Create a new template for this page by copying over another template file and giving it a header like this to name it.

```
<?
/*
Template Name: About Us / Team / Whatever
*/
?>
```

And in the page call only the information you want with something like this:

```
//Set up the Loop
<?php 
    global $post;
    $args = array (
    'category' => 4,
    'order' => 'ASC');  
        $teamposts = get_posts( $args );
        foreach( $teamposts as $post ) :    setup_postdata($post); ?>


//Call the information you want - put them in <li> if you need

<?php the_title();?>
    <?php the_excerpt();?> //OR the_content
<?php the_post_thumbnail('new-image-size');?>

//Close the loop
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

You can then go on to call anything else you want or run another loop on the same page to call other information.

To get the right sized thumbnail you have called 'new-image-size' - to set this up add a line like this to your functions.php file.

```
// Post Thumbnails
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

    // name of the thumbnail, width, height, crop mode
    add_image_size( 'front-page-services',  450, 270, true );
```